# Java semaphore for parking lot

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, semaphore

I'm trying to make a parking lot program. I've got multiple threads that put car objects into a queue, then into a shared buffer. Once the sharedBuffer reaches the maximum of 50 elements.

Here is the problem: Once the shared Buffer reaches the maximum amount of elements. I want the thread to start queuing up elements to the queue. Instead the thread waits for the semaphore to open a spot.

```
public class Buffer {

    private LinkedList queue = new LinkedList();
    private Semaphore spots = new Semaphore(50);

    public synchronized void put(String car) {
        try {
            spots.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        queue.addLast(car);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized String get() throws InterruptedException {
        String t = (String) queue.removeFirst();
        spots.release();
        notifyAll();
        return t;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return queue.size();
    }
}
```

Method in my Queue class that either adds the car to the buffer or adds it straight to the queue if the buffer is full.

```
public void addToQueue(int queue) {
        if (queue == 1 && northQueue<20) {
               if(buffer.getSize()==50){
                  northQueue++;
               }else{
                  buffer.put("Volvo");
               }
        }
} 


public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // System.out.println("Thread: " + threadNumber);
        eq.addToQueue(threadNumber);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure, a semaphore is the right concept for your problem? It is designed to block a thread, until there is a free "spot". What exactly do you want to do with your code

Comment: I don't know if I can explain it correctly but I'll try. Basically I'm trying to make an parking lot program. I'm using a threadpool with 3 threads that run concurrently. Thre is 4 entrance to the lot, north, east, south and west. I'm adding cars to each of these entrance, if there is a spot in the lot there shouldn't be a queue in the entrance. But if the shared buffer (the lot) is full there should be queues stacking up in each of the entrances.

Comment: can you show the code, running in the threads?

Comment: Basically just a thread that calls the method above 'addToQueue'

Comment: I mean you might be right that I shouldn't use semaphores but I don't see any other way to do it since it wont ever be exactly 50 will either be 48 or 52 in my case. Since I'm putting in 3 cars with 3 different threads almost at the same time.

Comment: i will try to reconstruct your problem. A solution would be to use a syncrhonized block: private Object lock = new Object(); and then everytime you are adding or removing a car (f.e. in your addToQueue) synchronized(lock){ //add car here}. This way only one thread at a time can put a car in the queue

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same way i use a monitor in the buffer class?

`public synchronized void put(){
     //code
     notifyAll();
}`

Comment: hmm, just tested your code and it is not blocking for me, when the buffer is full, it is queuing up the elements, until the queue is full (20 ist your limit): https://codepaste.net/y9f9kr
What i mean by using synchronized block is:https://codepaste.net/yzo1n4

Comment: Thanks it worked! Got a problem though, when I exit a car, the if statement biffer.getSize()==50; won't be true so it goes down to the else statement and adds a car to the lot. But if in my case two of the threads gets in the put state but only one is allowed in and takes the last spot. The thread will be waiting for the last spot and won't be adding cars to it's queue. Where in this case 4 cars have exited and the south entrance thread is stuck http://imgur.com/a/3sE2Z . Really apreciate the help man! Already helped alot

Comment: Why are you invoking `notifyAll()`? I can see no corresponding `wait()`. Furthermore, `addToQueue(int)` isn't synchronized, hence, your consecutive `if` statements aren't atomic, so you can't rely on their results in such an concurrent environment. Have a look at *Hilzer's barbershop* which is a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks worked now! I added mutual execlusion to the addToQueue method and now they are atomic.

Comment: @Amar I am not clear about what your exact requirement is and the real trouble you are facing? could you please explain in more detail?? And I see lots of possible errors in your code. Please update your question, I would be able to help then. :))

Comment: For each of the four entrances, do we need to maintain separate queues for stacking up vehicles, if the park is full?